# What is the lady saying between 0:45 and 0:47 in this radio episode by SRF?

Tags: german-to-english, transcription

I am trying to transcribe the following [radio episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cnzs3E4b1uA), but cannot understand what is said by the host between 0:45 and 0:47. Starting at 0:37, I have the following:

> Also haben wir uns gesagt machen wir eine Folge dazu. Voilà, das ist News Plus. Ich bin Rina Telli ______**I do not understand this**.

I think it maybe something like "salut zusammen", but I am not sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is Swiss German *sali zäme*, which corresponds to Standard German *salut zusammen*.

Comment: Is *salut* Standard German? I would rather translate Swiss *sali* as *hallo*.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: Sure, and it is even in the Duden, though with the spelling [salü](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/salue), which I strongly dislike (just like «Portmonee» or «Majonäse»). I will continue writing it as «salut» (another attested spelling, cf. DWDS [salut](https://www.dwds.de/wb/salut)).

Answer (score 12):

As covered in [mach's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/76612/11180), this is a colloquial Swiss German [greeting](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeting). Since [there is no standardized written form of Swiss German](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_German#Orthography), you may find it written in various different ways:

First word:

- [Sälü](https://berndeutsch.ch/words/11988)
- Sali
- Salü
- Säli
- Sälüü
- Salut

Second word:

- [Zäme](https://berndeutsch.ch/words/11040)
- Zsäme

The host is mostly speaking [Swiss Standard German](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Standard_German#Spoken_Swiss_Standard_German), which is similar to [Standard High German](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German) but with a slight Swiss accent and a slightly different vocabulary and grammar.

For the greeting, however, the host [code-switches](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching) full-on into their regional [Swiss German](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_German) dialect, then immediately back to Swiss Standard German. It is quite common for professional speakers to inject some "color" into their speaking by switching to their native dialect or language for small interjections like greetings and [farewells](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Parting_phrase) which are not relevant for understanding the topic they are talking about.

For example, a speaker from Texas may speak [General American English](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American_English), but greet the audience with "[Howdy](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Howdy)" instead of "Good evening" and address them with "[y'all](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%27all)". A speaker from Hamburg may speak Standard German, but greet the audience with "[Moin](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Moin)" instead of "Guten Abend". A speaker of Indian descent may speak in a generic English dialect, but greet the audience with "[Namasté](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Namaste)" instead of "Good evening".

Comment: While there is not a standardized orthography, I would like to point out that there is the Idiotikon, a "Dictionary of the Swiss German language". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerisches_Idiotikon